# Enthought Canopy crashes upon opening mac

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

So yesterday I updated to Enthought version 1.1 and now it refuses to open. I've rebooted my computer as well as did a re-install of enthought canopy. I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 1989, in main
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 1021, in main
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 1012, in _      kill_leftover_procs
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/app/running_process_manager.py", line 116, in kill_leftover_procs
 File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/app/running_process_manager.py", line 59, in lock
LockError: Lock could not be acquired
```

I have no idea what's going on here. I've sent the error report to enthought but does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I did it. Try searching for these files in your Terminal. They're inside your .canopy folder. Make sure that you're working on your root directory. They're not searchable via Finder. My Canopy's finally working now. Hope this helps.

- proc_manager.lock
- process.lck
- running_procs.pkl

Comment: This worked! I removed the first and last file and now it works! In case anyone reads this later, you can use cd /.canopy and then rm prock_manager.lock, and such

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it seems like a lock file didn't get cleaned in the process. Look into the `~/.canopy` folder and remove the `process.lck` file. You may also start your Activity Monitor and make sure there is no stray canopy or python process, and kill it if there is (or log out of OSX and log back in, which will do the same thing). Canopy will run as normally after that.

Comment: No such file or directory exists. Nor is there any directory. Since I re-installed it canopy has yet to run once so there is no processes (I did double check)